# Redirect browser http request to local server

Tags: nginx, proxy, http, port-forwarding

I have now the following flow.

```
example.com => https://example-example.mycompany.com => myproxy => someServer
```

I am right now developing `myproxy` and it changes the answers that the clients of the website `example.com` are receiving.

In order to test this, I thought that the best idea I could come up with was changing my local machine (in which I have an instance of `myproxy` running on the port `8080`) redirect the requests that `example-example.mycompany.com` does to `localhost:8080`

I have tried with `nginx` adding the following configurationbut I was unable... and also changing `/etc/hosts` didn't help me.

#### Question

Is there any way to change the call of `example-example.mycompany.com` JUST for my computer, so that while I am testing there is no client of `example.com` affected by the bugs that might appear?

#### Trials

Nginx setup

`docker run --name my-custom-nginx-container -v $(pwd)/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -p 80:80 -p 3000:8080 --rm -d nginx`

nginx.conf

```
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name example-example.mycompany.com;

            location / {
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
                    proxy_redirect http://localhost:3000/ https://$server_name/;
            }
    }
```

/etc/hosts (not added at the same time as the nginx setup)

`127.0.0.1    example-example.mycompany.com`